# Android Simple imageView Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-widget

I'm trying to make a widget that only consists of one imageView and when you tap it, it changes to another image, randomly selected from the six images I have made.

My problem is, is that there are no good explanations for how to make widgets, so I don't know how to do this.

I have already made a widget layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/widget_description"
        android:onClick="widgetOnClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_widget" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to make some code in my .java file, but that didn't do anything.

```
package com.ggblbl.widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class RandomSideWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.random_side_widget);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    public void widgetOnClick(View v) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;

        switch(number) {
            case 1:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_blue);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_green);
                break;
            case 3:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_orange);
                break;
            case 4:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_pink);
                break;
            case 5:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_red);
                break;
            case 6:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_yellow);
                break;
            default:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_widget);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I use API level 15.

Comment: The [developer page on App Widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) is rather detailed. Have you gone through that?

Comment: I really tried (multiple times), yes, but I didn't understand much of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PendingIntent and IntentService to handle clicks from the widget.
Inside the `updateAppWidget()` method, put code as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1001 + appWidgetId, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);
```

Place your onclick stuffs inside the `onHandleIntent` method of your custom class which extends `IntentService`.

And also call the same method `updateAppWidget()` after update has been made.

Comment: The whole problem is that I don't know what to code there and in the layout file.

Comment: to create IntentService, right click on java>new>Service>Service(IntentService), you dont need to worry about editing manifest.

Comment: @ggblbl write your click handling code inside the onHandleIntent() method of your IntentService.

Comment: Now I got these errors in my setImageResource cases:


`Method setImageResource must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.  Examples of errors flagged by this inspection:
Passing the wrong type of resource integer (such as R.string) to an API that expects a different type (such as R.dimen).

Comment: Forgetting to invoke the overridden method (via super) in methods that require it
Calling a method that requires a permission without having declared that permission in the manifest
Passing a resource color reference to a method which expects an RGB integer value.
...and many more.  For more information, see the documentation at http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html`

Comment: Man, I see a problem here. You should first learn basics of Java, then basics of Android and then only you can work on widgets. Sorry, I can't help you further.

Comment: Aww... Sorry to have bothered you then.
I'll get back when I've learnt Java a bit more then..

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.YOUR_IMAGEVIEW_ID,R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);
```

instead of

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.widget_blue);
```